# How to Gracefully Throw Exceptions in Custom Content Neogtiation Formatters in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, error-handling, formatting, content-negotiation

So I am building out a custom content negotiation formatter [like this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters/sample/Formatters/VcardOutputFormatter.cs) for a custom data format that we need to use in our .NET Core API.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using CustomFormatterDemo.Models;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace CustomFormatterDemo.Formatters
{
    #region classdef
    public class VcardOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
    #endregion
    {
        #region ctor
        public VcardOutputFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/vcard"));

            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
            SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
        }
        #endregion

        #region canwritetype
        protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            if (typeof(Contact).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
                || typeof(IEnumerable<Contact>).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            {
                return base.CanWriteType(type);
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region writeresponse
        public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
        {
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider = context.HttpContext.RequestServices;
            var logger = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<VcardOutputFormatter>)) as ILogger;

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            var buffer = new StringBuilder();
            if (context.Object is IEnumerable<Contact>)
            {
                foreach (Contact contact in context.Object as IEnumerable<Contact>)
                {
                    FormatVcard(buffer, contact, logger);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var contact = context.Object as Contact;
                FormatVcard(buffer, contact, logger);
            }
            await response.WriteAsync(buffer.ToString());
        }

        private static void FormatVcard(StringBuilder buffer, Contact contact, ILogger logger)
        {
            buffer.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCARD");
            buffer.AppendLine("VERSION:2.1");
            buffer.AppendFormat($"N:{contact.LastName};{contact.FirstName}\r\n");
            buffer.AppendFormat($"FN:{contact.FirstName} {contact.LastName}\r\n");
            buffer.AppendFormat($"UID:{contact.ID}\r\n");
            buffer.AppendLine("END:VCARD");
            logger.LogInformation("Writing {FirstName} {LastName}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Obviously, I can just do something like `throw new Exception("this doesn't work")`, but that is just going to give the API consumer a 500 response. Curious how I can throw more graceful errors with particular codes or, at the very least, the error details for the 500 status.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpResponse` class has a [`StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.statuscode) property, so you can just set that. Then you can set the body to an error message of some sort if you'd like.

The status code should probably reflect what's wrong. So if the request just had bad data, you could return [`400 Bad Request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400):

```
context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
```

Comment: sure, but `WriteResponseBodyAsync` is returning a task, not a status code

Comment: I'm not suggesting you return a status code. You just set the status code in the response.